# How to list peers to be connected to video chat on PEERJS and Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc, videochat, peerjs

I've followed the tutorial over building video chat with usage of PeerJs and Angular 4 (http://tphangout.com/angular-2-videochat-using-peerjs/)
Tutorial descibes it for ANg2 , but i was able to launch it with Ang 4

I plan to have a user, which sees the list of other others and can connect to any of them.

Decided to check if someone done this and might advise on following:
1) What is the best way to list users connected to Peer Server? Can this be done with some query ?
2) How to refresh the list if other users are available or disconnected?

So far, easiest way for me would be to store id of connected users in DB and query upon user visiting specific route.

ANy suggestions?

PeerJS is quite outdated, lib wasnt renewed for quite long. Ive researched and there are other options like simplewebrtc (works in chrome, ios etc) , easyrtc and others. The problem is that for those libraries there are no demo projects with Angular 2/4.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

You should save the peerjs id's to a database table, and then each client can show a list of them.

Have a look at https://github.com/mikkelking/meteor-video-call

Which is written in Meteor and Angular1.5 - it's really easy to run up, just follow the instructions (install Meteor first). It uses Meteor's reactive database to do live updates of the web pages. It uses the public peerjs server, and will only work on localhost - use Firefox for one end and Chrome for the other end of the video call.

You can ask more me questions if you want.

Comment: Ive used peerJS at the end and stored list in DB
Was the easiest solution for me
Now i switched to 3rd party tokbox lib

Comment: it seems peerjs-server has listAllPeers but I think this works only if you host in a dedicated server instead the shared host which is by default, also it says should have directory listing enabled for this to work